# jQuery get value of hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got an ajax call that returns something like this:

```
<p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addressOpt">
    John Paul Jones                     <br/>
    399 OAK ST          <br/>
    DELROY ND 30254     <br/> 

    <input type="hidden" name="XNAME" value="   John Paul Jones">
    <input type="hidden" name="XADD1" value="399 OAK ST">
    <input type="hidden" name="XADD2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="XCITY" value="DELROY">
    <input type="hidden" name="XSTA" value="ND">
    <input type="hidden" name="XZIP" value="30254">
    <input type="hidden" name="XPHON" value="">
    </a>
</p>
<p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addressOpt">
    John Paul Jones                     <br/>
    2680 PALUMBO DRIVE          <br/>
    LEXINGTON KY 40509      <br/> 
    8592667227  
    <input type="hidden" name="XNAME" value="John Paul Jones">
    <input type="hidden" name="XADD1" value="2680 PALUMBO DRIVE">
    <input type="hidden" name="XADD2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="XCITY" value="LEXINGTON">
    <input type="hidden" name="XSTA" value="KY">
    <input type="hidden" name="XZIP" value="40509">
    <input type="hidden" name="XPHON" value="8592667227">
    </a>
</p>
```

So I want to get every hidden value when any of those links are clicked.

I tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addressOpt', function(e) {
        alert($("[name=XCITY]").val());
});
```

But always gives me back the value of the first element (DELROY), even if I click the second.

I know I've got to use 'this' but don't know who to use it with the attribute equals selector.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have inputs nested into a link?

Comment: You wan't to get every hidden value or just one value? your topic and content doesnt match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addressOpt', function(e) {
    alert($(this).find("[name=XCITY]").val()); 
});
```

You can use $(this) to find the html dom element and get this value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the each function to get all the hidden data when you click the link using this code

```
$(document).on('click', '.addressOpt', function (e) {
    $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WrhCe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work:

```
$(".addressOpt").on("click", function(e) {
    alert($(this).find("input[name='XCITY']").val());
});
```

It should find the hidden fields within the `<a>` that has been clicked.

I would also use `e.preventDefault();` instead of `href=javascript:void(0);`.

Answer (score 0):

well first I suggest you to put the result in an array and show the value you need like this

```
var elems = $("[name=XCITY]");

alert($(elems[0]).val()); // will show "DELROY"
alert($(elems[1]).val()); // will show "LEXINGTON"
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem because you are saying

```
alert($("[name=XCITY]").val());
```

So it's returning value of first element with that name.

Say this. It'll get the current clicked `anchor` and give the value of element having name `XCITY` in that `anchor`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.addressOpt', function(e) {
    alert($(this).find("[name=XCITY]").val());
});
```